# Schematic title block question

Tags: schematics

Does the second schematic sheet title block need all the same information as the first sheet. To me it seems kind of redundant to keep the signoffs and proprietary statement...

Comment: It makes sense to keep it common across all sheets.

Comment: @user41041 Yes, what if the sheets get separated, the identifiers need to be on all sheets.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. All information should be on all sheets. Consider that the schematic could be printed, and the sheets separated. A copyright notice on page one is not much use when someone copies page two.

Put it another way, why *not* have all info on all sheets?

If it's space - you're already doing it wrong.